# How to connect to Oracle database running on AWS RDS using Rstudio

Tags: r, oracle, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I'm using RJDBC to connect to the database, but I'm not able to connect to exact schema in which my target tables are located.

I need some mechanism where I can connect to the exact schema I need instead of root schema , Also need suggestions, as `dbreadtable` and `dbwritetable` are not working.

Thanks in advance.

```
library(RJDBC)
library(DBI)

jdbcDriver = JDBC(driverClass = "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver",classPath="C:\\Users\\rishi\\Documents\\ojdbc6.jar",identifier.quote = NA)

jdbcConnection =dbConnect(jdbcDriver, "jdbc:oracle:thin:@xxx.rds.amazonaws.com:1526:saix", "saix_master", "password")

con <- jdbcConnection 

###
dbGetQuery(con, "select count(*) from saix_schema.saix_identity")
```

Comment: What exactly about `dbreadtable` and `dbwritetable` are not working? Could you list your error log?

Comment: Trying to read a table
#############
saix_identity_knowledge_iq <-  dbReadTable(jdbcConnection,"saix_identity_knowledge_iq")
#############
Error in .verify.JDBC.result(r, "Unable to retrieve JDBC result set for ",  : 
  Unable to retrieve JDBC result set for SELECT * FROM "saix_identity_knowledge_iq" (ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
)

Comment: +1. you might want to check out `ROracle` package. do let us know if AWS is adding a additional auth layer.